# IdHTTP Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, embarcadero

Нужно реализовать постоянную закачку страницы с сайта.
Есть компонент IdHTTTP у него метод Get получает страницу.
Я пытался зациклить программу таким вот способом, вроде и должно работать, а не работает...
используя события WorkEnd (после загрузки страницы)

```
procedure TForm12.IdHTTP1WorkEnd(ASender:TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode); 
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add('ADD');
  idHTTP1.Get('http://yandex.ru'); 
end;
```

По виду - рекурсия, но не совсем), так вот, выполняется всего лишь один раз, хотя после того как загрузило страницу, событие WorkEnd опять вызывает Get... загрузку и жду срабатывания WorkEnd, но оно уже не работает, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас dead-lock именно из-за рекурсии. У вас соединение не может закрыться. А новое не может открыться, потому что предыдущее не закрылось.

Как вариант (не знаю зачем это нужно, правда - от яндекса бана ждете?) повесьте на таймер вызов get. В OnWorkBegin ставьте флаг, что запрос идет. В OnWorkEnd снимайте. Таймер проверит этот флаг и если сброшен, запустит get снова.

Comment: Вариант, думаю таймер на 500мс подойдет, просто интернет очень слабый. А насчет яндекса, то для примера, там свой сайт будет (учебного заведения).